# Can any one tell what's wrong in my conversion from string to Date time

Tags: c#, datetime

I write the following code to convert a string to Date time but i am getting an exception so can any one help me

```
string str = "2/30/2011";

DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(str, "yyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`
```

Comment: What exception are you getting?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Other than the non-existing date? February 30th is not a date unless you're using MySQL...

Oh, and of course, your format is wrong. It should be `M/dd//yyyy` (because that's how your string is formatted).

Answer (score 2):

try

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(str, "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it like this:

```
string str = "2/30/2011";  
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(str, "M/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`
```

Answer (score 0):

Morover, you're using a format `yyMMdd` whereas your date is expressed in `M/dd/yy`